# Understanding ContentDocumentLink object API

Tags: content, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm), I am trying to understand the following point -

"For organizations with Communities enabled, a document can only be shared with users and groups that are a part of the community the file was created in"

Does this mean that content uploaded in community can only be shared with community users? However I am able to share content document (uploaded in the org outside the community context) with community user using below code snippet -

```
ContentDocumentLink cdLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
cdLink.ContentDocumentId = <content_document_Id>;
cdLink.LinkedEntityId = <community_user_account_id>;
cdLink.ShareType = 'I';
cdLink.Visibility = 'AllUsers';
insert cdLink;
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? As per statement in documentation, It says, any document created in community context i.e. by a community user can be shared to the users who belong to same community.

Comment: I am looking for clarification on this documentation. It seems confusing , mentioned that only content uploaded in community context can be shared with community user however i was able to do opposite. I have updated my question to reflect the user context.

Comment: Content uploaded in community context can be shared **ONLY** with community users. So, basically the file which is created in one community can be shared with users of the same community only. The statement is specific to sharing of files created in a community and not about what can be shared to community users.

Comment: ok thank you, write now in the code above sObject is used for linkedEntityId. Will try to do directly with community user and update you.